# multiple release versions with nebula

Tags: java, gradle, netflix-nebula-plugins

Is it possible to have multiple release git branches with the own release train? Suppose I have branches master, release/v1, release/v2. I'm pushing to the branches independently and want to create the independent releases. 
Example: 
master - version 0.0.x 
release/v1 - version 0.1.x 
release/v2 - version 0.2.x

I'm looking for nebula Gradle plugin, but don't know how to create independent releases in multiple brunches at the same time